# Preserve html characters within google-prettified pre element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

I'm attempted to include syntax highlighting into my Tumblr blog by means of `google-prettify` and some jQuery.

`Google-prettify` requires the `<pre>` element to have a class of `prettyprint` in order for it to highlight the syntax, but since I'm using markdown to create my Tumblr posts, I can't add a class to my `<pre>` elements.

My solution is to use this jQuery snippet to append the `prettyprint` class to the `<pre>` element:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('pre').addClass('prettyprint');
      prettyPrint();
});
</script>
```

This is working fine, but I'd like to be able to copy and paste the code that I want to show on my Tumblr, instead of converting all `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` every time I want to post a code snippet.

Using jQuery, I'd like to replace all the `<` and `>` with their corresponding html code, but only within the `pre` element. This however, might have some problems, as it would need to replace all of those before the code is *prettified*.

Could I append the new class, replace the tags, and then call `prettyPrint();` to intialize everything? Or should I just change the html characters into htmlentities by hand before posting the code?

**Little update:**
This script works with changing the `<` and `>`, except with `<body>`,`<html>`, and `<head>`...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
   var $pre = $('pre');
   $pre.html($pre.html().replace(/</g, 'f').replace(/>/g, 'l'));
});
</script>

<pre>
    <html></html>
    <body></body>
    <head><head>
    <i></i>
</pre>
```

*Note: I used `f` as the replacement just to test the code.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first replace all the ampersands with entities, and then the less than signs, you can use the returned string as a text-node in a `<pre>`, or any block container with its white-space set to 'pre'.

```
function stripX(str){
    return str.replace(/\&(?!(\w+;))/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
}
```

Comment: Why would I replace all the ampersands with html entities?